# AVRO schema optional fields are not compatible

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry

In [Confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#summary) they write that deletion and addition of optional AVRO fields preserve full AVRO compatibility. I need to update an AVRO schema by deletion of optional fields and by adding new optional fields. But Confluent schema registry responses with error 409, that the new schema is not compatible with the old schema.

I'm deleting the following field (in avsc syntax):

```
{
  "name" : "eligibility",
  "type" : [ {
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : "Scope"
  }, "null" ]
}
```

and adding these fields:

```
{
  "name" : "partyDataExt",
  "type" : [ {
    "type" : "record",
    "name" : "PartyDataExt",
    "fields" : [ {
      "name" : "dayOfDeath",
      "type" : [ {
        "type" : "int",
        "logicalType" : "date"
      }, "null" ]
    }, {
      "name" : "identified",
      "type" : [ "boolean", "null" ]
    } ]
  }, "null" ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "name" : "identificationDocument",
  "type" : [ "null", "Document" ]
}
```

**Question:** What exactly is meant by an optional AVRO field? Is it the `union {null, MyType}`, or the presence of the `default` parameter, or both, or something else?

In the case of the deleted "eligibility" field, it helps if the field has `"default":null`. This helps also for the added "identificationDocument" field, but not for the "partyDataExt" field.
When I switch the `"null"` and `"Document"` elements in the definition of "identificationDocument", adding the `default` parameter doesn't help either. It seems that `"null"` must be the first element in the the `"type"` array.

Comment: According to the [Avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schema_record), default values for union fields correspond to the *first* schema in the union.

Comment: @ChinHuang Unfortunately, this is not sufficient for Confluent schema registry to accept the schema change as compatible. The `"default":null` field parameter seems to be also necessary for this. But this is just a trial-and-error finding, the docs is vague.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you'll need to understand Apache Avro.

`default` fields in the reader schema are for [schema evolution](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schema_record):

> default: A default value for this field, **only used when reading**
> instances that lack the field for schema evolution purposes. The
> presence of a default value does not make the field optional at
> encoding time. [...] Avro encodes a field even if its value is equal
> to its default.

Also, ["null" goes first](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Unions) in a union:

> Note that when a default value is specified for a record field whose
> type is a union, **the type of the default value must match the first
> element** of the union. Thus, for unions containing "null", the "null"
> is usually listed first, since the default value of such unions is
> typically null.

There is no such thing as “optional” fields in Apache Avro documentation, but Confluent refers to fields having a default, which could be as simple as

```
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "field",
    "type": "string",
    "default": "default"
  }
]
```

You can also use unions and “null“ (first), but you don't have to.

That's it for Avro, so you can read data with a schema with extra fields that are not in the writers schema. Fields that are not in the reading schema are silently ignored, which Confluent refers to “deleted fields”.

As for Confluent Avro, they have different compatibility rules (and a different serialisation format) than Apache Avro, but these are documented in “[Compatibility Types](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#compatibility-types)” you cited.

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested in Confluent avro compatibility rules. "Optional" can have two meanings: either the field can have no value (null), or you are not required to specify the field but the value is still there (default). Only after plenty of experiments I realized that `default` is what the schema evolution needs, and you confirmed that to me. When I need a nullable field that can be deleted or added to a new avro version, I need both `union null` and `default null`. The specs and docs are vague in this regard, IMO.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand Avro: "null" is a value and gets encoded like any other value. It's impossible for an encoded field to have no value.

"default" has only meaning for the readers schema. For Avro, you always need a writers schema (to know how the data was encoded) and a readers schema, which indicates which fields you are interested in. There, you can mark a field as having a default when it is not present in the writers schema, otherwise you'll just get an error.

Comment: Technically, "null" is a value like any other, but logically, "null" is used to indicate that a field has no value. In order to allow a field to contain "null", you have to use `union null`. That's all clear. For me, the `default` param is problematic. What you write about the writer and reader schemas makes sense, but the tricky part is the schema registry. As I see it, "backward" and "forward" schema compatibility is about who's the owner of the schema (consumer vs producer), not about readers and writers. E.g. deleting an non-optional field is not a forward compatible change.

Comment: The Confluent schema registry is only made to transport the writer schema to the reader.

The “backward” and “forward” thing is an Confluent invention. In “Backward Compatibility” <https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#backward-compatibility> Confluent writes:

_`BACKWARD` compatibility means that consumers using the new schema can read data produced with the last schema._

“new schema” is here the reader and “last schema” the writer. “New” and “last” are misleading IMHO, because it depends in which order the Confluent Registry sees the schemata.

Comment: I think that in Confluent Kafka this works differently than in vanilla Kafka. Each message in a Confluent Kafka topic contains the associated writer's schema id. A consumer decodes the (binary) message using this writer's schema, read from schema registry. A consumer written e.g. in Python doesn't use any reader's schema. There's no way here for the message to not contain a field marked with `default`, it could not be decoded. A Java consumer, however, contains a compiled-in reader's schema and has a corresponding POJO model. Here the `default` may play a role, but I don't know which role.

Comment: How AVRO message exchange works in Confluent, see the numbered points in the chapter "Schema registry": https://tech.willhaben.at/kafka-and-the-avro-serialisation-system-fce8d9f1b35e

Comment: Confluent doesn't have a "different serialization format" for Avro. They use Avro's Java BinaryEncoder class, but just happen to prepend the data with a integer and `0x0`

Comment: @xarx There is no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". Confluent only writes the AvroSerializer classes, which work the same with "vanilla (Apache) Kafka"

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Apache Avro specifies Single-object encoding
 <https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#single_object_encoding> format i.e. for Kafka use. You can't read these with the Confluent Serializers, and what the Confluent serialisers produce is unreadable by Apache Avro serializers. Thats why i call these formats incompatible, and call what Confluent does “Confluent Avro”. You are right that Confluent Avro encoding uses major parts from Apache Avro, that's why it's still has “Avro” in its name.

Comment: @eik After the first 5 bytes of the record, it is that _binary encoding_, though, and can be used with regular Apache Avro parsers

Comment: @OneCricketeer There's no doubt about that. I haven't used vanilla Kafka, but as I understand it, producer and consumer may use different schemas there. And `default` is used to overcome the schema difference. On the other hand, in Confluent Kafka producer and consumer use the same schema (it's id is included in the message). So there's surely a difference (though not technical difference). What I currently don't understand enough, is the role of the reader's schema, e.g. in Java consumers.

Comment: @xarx No, they are not required to be the same. When using `GenericRecord` with a AvroDeserializer (again, can be used with **Apache** Kafka since that is all it is, and this is what you are using), it'll use the schema that is downloaded from the registry (by extracting the ID from the record) as the reader schema. If using a compiled SpecificRecord subclass, it'll instead use that schema

Comment: @OneCricketeer: No, you'll need the writers schema in any case, otherwise an Avro message in unreadable. The writers schema is essential information, and because *that* is encoded differently both formats (Avro single-object encoding and Confluent Avro) are incompatible. You're right that both use Avro binary encoding, though.

Comment: Agree to disagree. It's referred to as the "wire format". Confluent doesn't fork or maintain their own Avro. And the encoding is used for more than just that https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format

Comment: Perhaps you we should agree to: “Confluent libraries serialize to Confluent wire format, which - in the case of Avro - has an underlying Avro binary encoding embedded, which is unreadable without knowing the *exact* writers schema. The Confluent wire format is not readable with standard Avro serialisers.”

Comment: The point is that people often get confused that Confluent Avro is a centralized format - when you loose your Confluent registry, you loose *all* your data. with it. Avro is more distributed, especially when you consider object container files - they are self-describing.